# How to remove the tags from the starting and end of a sentence in a ml.transcription file and save it in a newml.transcription file using python?

Tags: python, linux, string, python-2.7, python-3.x

Current Format: I have a ml.transcription file which consist of sentences in the following manner- (having tag  in the beginning and end of a sentence, follow up by an serial id)

```
 1. <r>The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog </r> (umnle_001_001)
 2. <r> I think we should go get it now </r> (umnle_001_002)
 3. ......................................................
 4. <r> When I travel, I prefer to travel by air </r> (umnle_001_129)
 5. <r> The law was changed </r> (umtci_001_001)
 6. <r> This soup needs more salt </r> (umtci_001_002)
 7. .................................................
 8. .................................................
 9. <r> Tom sat two rows ahead of me </r> (umtci_001_197)
```

Desired Format: I need to save the desired result in the new file named as newml.transcription, after the conversion the desired format looks like-

```
 1. umnle_001_001 The quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog
 2. umnle_001_002 I think we should go get it now
 3. ......................................................
 4. umnle_001_129 When I travel, I prefer to travel by air
 5. umtci_001_001 The law was changed
 6. umtci_001_002 This soup needs more salt
 7. ......................................................
 8. ......................................................
 9. umtci_001_197 Tom sat two rows ahead of me
```

---------------------CODE------------------------------------

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

fo = open(" ml.transcription", "r")
y_list = []
for line in fo.readlines():
    a1 = line [-15:-2]
    a2 = line [4:]
    y = str(a1)+ " "+ str(a2)
    a3 = y[:-22]
    y_list.append(a3)
    print(a3)
fo.close()
fo = open("newml.transcription", "w")
for lines in y_list:
    fo.write(lines,"\n")
fo.close()
```

error which I am getting:

fo.write(lines,"\n")

TypeError: function takes exactly 1 argument (2 given)

Although the logic is correct in the above code and print the desired output, but this error creates a problem.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have tags  <r> and </r>  in the beginning and end of every sentences in the current format. Some how it is not representing in the main question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A crude way of doing this:

```
import re
with open("input", "r") as input:
    for line in input:
        print line.split("</r> ")[1][2:-2] + " " + line.split("r>")[1][1:-3]
```

The above prints to screen, you can pipe that to a file.
It assumes there is always a space after `<r>` as well as before and after `</r>`. It also assumes each line ends with a newline character.

Comment: Hi Pétur Ingi Egilsson, can you please fix the error in the above written code, which I have edited one day back in the main question.

Comment: @Andy Are you talking about your own code? ´fo.write(lines,"\n")´ does not look correct; I think it should be ´fo.write(lines + "\n")´